# "WARNING:tornado.access:404 POST /game (127.0.0.1) 1.96ms" while running my simple tornado script

Tags: jquery, python, tornado

Here's my tornado script, it's me trying to understand how to grab user input from a browser and pass it back to the `Game` class.

```python
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

def applicationInit():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", Game),
    ])

class Game(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("You made it!")
        self.render("game.html")

    def post(self):
        if self.get_argument("keyinput") is not None:
            k = int(self.get_argument("keyinput"))
            print (k)

app = applicationInit()
app.listen(8080)
print ("Starting...")
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

... and here is my `game.html` that is referenced by the `Game.write()` in the `get` method.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pyablo</title>

  </head>
  <body>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on("keydown", this, function(e){
                var key = e.which;
                switch (key)
                {
                    case 87:
                        $.post("/game", { 'keyinput': '1' }, function(data) {
                            alert("You pressed UP. "+ data);
                        });
                }
            });
         });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, I know much more about Python than I do jQuery/HTML/JavaScript. I am getting this error whenever I go to 127.0.0.1:8080...

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 POST /game (127.0.0.1) 1.96ms
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For the POST error, you are posting to /game but only registered the / path. You should POST to /.

The error on the GET is strange as you are getting jquery from a cdn and the version in the error doesn't match the one in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly define your handlers.

If you want to maka a POST request to `/game`, you need to define that path for your `Game` RequestHandler class to handle it.

You can serve your `game.html` file with a `StaticFileHandler`.
Make a directory `files`, rename `game.html` to `index.html` and put it into `files` directory.

Your code should then be:

```
def applicationInit():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/game", Game),
        (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './files', 'default_filename': 'index.html'}),
    ])

class Game(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        if self.get_argument("keyinput") is not None:
            k = int(self.get_argument("keyinput"))
            print (k)
```